# Wrong content-type for batch (text/csv; charset=UTF-8), job is of type: text/csv

Tags: bulk-api, workbench

I am trying to insert a batch job with the Bulk API and Workbench.

I am getting following error :

> ```
>     Wrong content-type for batch (text/csv; charset=UTF-8), job is of type: text/csv
> ```

These are my settings:
[image]

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

I removed

> ; charset=UTF-8

in the header part and it worked.

Thanks